# Local Variable C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

how can I get a local variable?

I have this code

```
if (ctrl is Control)
{
    Control c = (Control)ctrl;
    foreach (object innerCtrl in c.Controls)
    {
        if (innerCtrl is System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox)
        if (((CheckBox)innerCtrl).Checked == true)
        {
            string resultado = (((CheckBox)innerCtrl).Text);
        }
        else
        {
            TextBox1.Text = "não";
        }
    }
}
```

how can I get the variable **resultado**?

Comment: Where would you like to get it?

Comment: Please post the method that this code belongs to and where you want to retrieve it.

Comment: Please don’t write `== true`.

Comment: @minitech: there is one exception: if it is a `Nullable<bool>` it does mean more. But yes, in this case, please don't.

Answer (score 10):

This answer makes a huge assumption about what you mean by, "how can I get the variable" (you already *have* the variable...).

You can declare the variable at any scope you need it:

```
string resultado = null;
if (ctrl is Control)
{
    Control c = (Control)ctrl;
    foreach (object innerCtrl in c.Controls)
    {
        if (innerCtrl is System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox)
        {
            if (((CheckBox)innerCtrl).Checked)
            {
                resultado = (((CheckBox)innerCtrl).Text);
            }
            else
            {
                TextBox1.Text = "não";
            }
        }
    }
}

if (resultado != null) /* use the variable */
```

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Change the definition to something that will compile:</strike>
It appears that you were just attempting to **bold** the variable name and it came off with asterisks around it - my apologies.

If you want to get at it outside the loop, then define it above with `c` like this:

```
Control c = (Control)ctrl;
string resultado = null;
```

and then just use it later like this:

```
resultado = (((CheckBox)innerCtrl).Text);
```

and if you want the variable to be `global` then define it in the class. Assume the class is something like this:

```
public class YourClass
{
    string resultado = null;
}
```

and now you don't need to define it anywhere else, just use it in the method.

Comment: I want to get the local variable and make it global ...
I want to save the result into a control button

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you might get multiple results. I would recommend using a [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) to store all the results. This way you can access the List after the function has completed and use that to access all the values.

```
List<String> results = new List<String>;

if (ctrl is Control)
{
    Control c = (Control)ctrl;
    foreach (object innerCtrl in c.Controls)
    {
        if (innerCtrl is System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox)
            if (((CheckBox)innerCtrl).Checked == true)
            {
                string resultado = (((CheckBox)innerCtrl).Text);
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(resultado))
                    results.Add(resultado);
            }
            else
            {
                TextBox1.Text = "não";
            }
    }
}

if (results.Count > 0)
{
    // We got results. Do something with our results.
    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        Console.Write(results);
    }
}
```

I would recommend that you move your code into it's own function. Normally I prefer to have my functions do only one thing to keep it simple, but as a start you could turn it into something like this.

```
public List<String> FetchTextFromCheckBoxes(Control cntrl)
{
    List<String> results = new List<String>();

    if (ctrl is Control)
    {
        Control c = (Control)ctrl;
        foreach (object innerCtrl in c.Controls)
        {
            if (innerCtrl is System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox)
                if (((CheckBox)innerCtrl).Checked == true)
                {
                    string resultado = (((CheckBox)innerCtrl).Text);
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(resultado))
                        results.Add(resultado);
                }
                else
                {
                    TextBox1.Text = "não";
                }
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

Then you simply use it like this in the main part of your application.

```
List<String> results = FetchTextFromCheckBoxes(ctrl);

if (results.Count > 0)
{
    // We got results. Do something with our results.
    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        Console.Write(results);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, perhaps the more likely solution given the OP is using checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that local variables in the method are always declared on the top of the scope by compiler, no matter the real *visibility* scope in the code. So there is no any performance/memory impact in moving variable out of `if` statement, like this:

```
foreach (object innerCtrl in c.Controls)
{
     if (innerCtrl is System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox) {

        string resultado = string.Empty;
        if (((CheckBox)innerCtrl).Checked)
        {
             resultado = (((CheckBox)innerCtrl).Text);
        }
        else
        {
           TextBox1.Text = "não";
        }

        //CAN READ variable here
     }
}
```

Comment: I kinda doubt the OP was worried about the performance of declaring their variable in the `if` statement :)